# How to pick an orthogonal basis from same eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

From a matrix I gathered three eigenvalues, two of them were $-1$. And so by solving for all the eigenvectors for the eigenvalue $-1$, I got the following matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}X=0$$

How would I go about choosing two vectors from here, which are orthogonal to each other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring two eigenvectors for the same reccuring eigenvalue](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179640/declaring-two-eigenvectors-for-the-same-reccuring-eigenvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that the eigenvector $(x,y, z)^T$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $-1$ satisfies $$2x - y + z = 0 \tag 1$$  one eigenvector is $$ u = (1, 2, 0)^T$$ now we add another constraint on the second eigenvector to make it orthogonal to $u$ which is $$x + 2y = 0 \tag 2  $$ we can solve $(1)$ and $2$ by setting $x = 2, y = -1, z = -5$ so the orthogonal eigenvectors are $$  u = (1, 2, 0)^T, \, v = (2, -1, -5)^T.$$